# Tuleap: Proper way to link artifacts

Tags: tuleap

Does the artifact linking have to be done based on the Project Tracker Hierarch.  For example, the following is the tracker hierarchy:

Epic
==>User Story
=====> Task

From within the user story can I enter the artifact Id# of the Epic.  Will it affect the display on the Agile Dashboard?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It will automatically add the user story as child of the Epic

Answer (score 0):

No, the artifact linking reacts based on Tracker Hierarchy but you don't have to link based on tracker hierarchy.

If you link a User Story to an Epic, your Hierarchy being Epic==>User Story==>Task, Tuleap will automatically revert the link so that it is Epic which links the User Story. So There is no consequences whether you do it a way or another as long as the hierarchy is correctly set.